# Python default value in constractor is ignored?

Tags: python, constructor, default-value

I'm new to python. When I code in Python I notice this strange behavior:

Class x:

```
class x:
    x1 = 0

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x1 = x
```

Class xcontainer:

```
class xContainer:
    coint = []

    def __init__(self, coint = []):
        self.coint = coint

    def add_x(self, x):
        self.coint.append(x)
```

when I try to run this code:

```
def Main():
    list_xcon = []
    for i in range (0,2):
        xcon = xContainer()
        for j in range (i, i+1):
            xcon.add_x(x(j))
        list_xcon.append(xcon)

    for xcont in list_xcon:
        for xc in xcont.coint:
            print xc.x1
```

I get those results:

> 0 1 0 1

but when I run this code:

```
def Main():
    list_xcon = []
    for i in range (0,2):
        listt = []
        xcon = xContainer(listt)
        for j in range (i, i+1):
            xcon.add_x(x(j))
        list_xcon.append(xcon)

    for xcont in list_xcon:
        for xc in xcont.coint:
            print xc.x1
```

I get those results:

> 0 1

Why is that? According to `class xcontainer`, the default of `coint` should be `[]` - empty list. So why sending empty list change the result?

By the way, I read that using `coint = None` as default and checking `if coint is None: coint = []` is better way, but it seems that it does not change the results here.

I will appreciate any explanation. I'm confused.

Thanks.

Comment: Because you're using a *mutable default argument* in your `__init__`

Comment: Also, stop creating class-level variables (you could call them "static") that you then immediately shadow on each instance in your initializers. Python != Java

Comment: @MosesKoledoye didn't know this so I didn't know that exactly to search to find the answer. It really is duplicate and can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well as I said, I really am new to this language and I did code in java most of the time. thanks, it really helpful advice.

Comment: It is a very common mistake. Java's class system is more like C++, whereas Python's [class semantics are closer to Simula3/Smalltalk](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). I think you will find that Python is actually quite straightforward if you don't bring in any of your assumptions from Java. Everything definined at the class level *belongs to the class*, and keep in mind, in Python, classes are just another object. Anything assigned to `self` inside a method will belong to the *instance*.